# How do I copy a single PDF file and batch paste it into hundreds of files with a specific naming convention based on a source .csv or Excel file?

Tags: batch-file, rename, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy a single PDF document into several hundred PDF documents, but they have to have a specific naming convention based on specific user data stored in a .csv (or text, or Excel, any of these sources is fine). I imagine I could use PowerShell for this, but don't know how to approach.

Example:
Take a single PDF - sample.pdf - and rename into 00003021_20160204.pdf where the '00003021_20160204' is one specific user record in the source .csv. I would then copy sample.pdf and repeat the above process several hundred times until my source list was complete.

Note, these are sequential numbers, so I have to rely on the source data.

I tried search stack and google, but found nothing. Though I'm open to suggestions on how I (or others) might better search for this solution in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: Someone might be able to give you a better answer if you provided better details. SO is really not a code writing service.  It is a forum to help programmers with their existing code.

Comment: Copy-Item and change the -Destination to the new file name. Wrap that in a loop that gets/builds the needed new file name.

Answer (score 0):

`for /F %%p in (files.txt) do copy %1 "%%p.pdf"`

where files.txt has a number on each line and the first parameter is the pdf you want to copy.